# How do you include a Controller plugin (Zend Framework)

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, path, include

I use `MVC` for `ASP.NET` and its allot simpler than this. 
All I want to do is include a controller `plugin` into the project.

I have a class defined in session.php :

```
   class session extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract{
        //Code
    }
```

The file structure looks like this
/application
 /configs
 /controllers
  /plugins
   /session.php
 /layouts
 /models
 /views

I have crawled the web and no one offers a simple explination on how to do this.
What i have tried :

```
application.ini
resources.frontController.plugins.route = "Application_Controllers_Plugins_Session"
resources.frontController.plugins.route = "Application/Controllers/Plugins/Session"
resources.frontController.plugins[]  = "Controllers_Plugins_Session"
resources.frontController.plugins[]  = "Controllers/Plugins/Session"

Bootstrap.php : 
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->registerPlugin(new Application_Controllers_Plugins_SessionPlugin(), 1);
```

I tried all this and a whole lot more. If I could just understand the science of including classes I can figure it out from there.

The error that I get is always Class 'blah' not found in blah on line x

Comment: Do you have anything autoloader related in your application.ini?

Comment: No autoloader stuff :  phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
resources.view[] =
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're declaring the class `session`, but then trying to instantiate that class using a number of other class names. It looks like you're following the standard resource autoloader file structure, and since you've declared an appnamespace of `Application`, your plugin class should be declared as:

```
class Application_Plugin_Session extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    ...
}
```

(case sensitive). It's filename must be `Session.php` (uppercase S). It should then be autoloaded correctly.

Then you just need to register the plugin with the front controller. You can either do this in application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.plugins[]  = "Application_Plugin_Session"
```

or in the bootstrap class:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->registerPlugin(new Application_Plugin_Session());
```

(don't do both as they do the same thing).

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I tried your suggestion and I still get Fatal error: Class 'Application_Plugin_Session' not found in .....\Zend\Application\Resource\Frontcontroller.php on line 117. My question is this where do I put the Session.php file for it to be included? i tried application/controllers/Plugin, application/Plugin, and application/../library/Plugin. the later because of the ini file had this : includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library".

Comment: The file should be at `application/plugins/Session.php` - could you give that a try?

Answer (score 0):

Holy Crap! I figured it out.
I found the answer here http://grover.open2space.com/content/autoloading-plugins-zend_application.

Ok, My bootstrap.php, (in part), looks like this:

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{
    $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
    'namespace' => '',
    'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH));
    return $moduleLoader;
}   

protected function _initPlugins() {
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->registerPlugin(new Plugin_YourClassNameHere());
}
```

This absolutly will not work without _initAutoload();
Next I have my class. Naming convention is huge.

```
class Plugin_YourClassNameHere extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
    {
        //Code
    }
```

This class is in a file called YourClassNameHere.php. Now this is where I got stuck. Where do I put the file? Well as it turns out, there is an Autoloader.php file that I found in .....php\PEAR\Zend\Application\Module. This file is not in your project. This file already defines where you put your plugins. (Amoung other things). So I found this :

```
public function initDefaultResourceTypes()
    {
        $basePath = $this->getBasePath();
        $this->addResourceTypes(array(
            ........
            ,
            'model'   => array(
                'namespace' => 'Model',
                'path'      => 'models',
            ),
            'plugin'  => array(
                'namespace' => 'Plugin',
                'path'      => 'plugins',
            ),
            .......
           ,
        ));
        $this->setDefaultResourceType('model');
    }
```

Notice that the plugin namespace is 'Plugin' and the path is 'plugins' WITH AN S!! So I put the YourClassNameHere.php file in application/plugins and now everything works!